# Cache a request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-request

Here is actual code that works well and only makes a request to an api with some params :

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET data by sportId */
router.get('/:locale/:sportId/:federationId/:date', function(req, res) {
    var date = req.params.date;
    var locale = req.params.locale;
    var sportId = req.params.sportId;
    var federationId = req.params.federationId;

   request(getEventsOptions(sportId, federationId, date, locale), function(error, response, body) {
    res.send(body);
   });
});

// get options for request
function getEventsOptions(sportId, federationId, date, locale)
{
    return {
        url: `http://myapi.com/sporting-event/sport/${sportId}/date-from/${date}`,
       headers: {
         'accept': 'application/json',
         'dateTo': date,
         'federationIds': federationId,
         'X-Application-ID': 'sporter',
         'Accept-Language': locale,
     }
 };
```

}

I receive an array of objects (each object is a sport game with an unique eventId). so each time i call this route i make a new call to the api, what i want is to interrogate the api only if the object of an event is different (for example if the score of the game has changed). Do u have an idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose that [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) serves. Since `getEventsOptions` accepts scalar arguments, this simplifies a way it should be memoized; cache key can be calculated from stringified arguments, e.g. with [Lodash `memoize`](https://lodash.com/docs#memoize) or similar implementation:

```
function memoize(fn, getCacheKey = ([firstArg]) => firstArg) {
  const cache = new Map();
  return (...args) => {
    const cacheKey = getCacheKey(args);

    if (!cache.has(cacheKey))
      cache.set(cacheKey, fn(...args));

    return cache.get(cacheKey);
  }
}
```

It's preferable to use promises because promise object can be cached as a result, while this will be hard to do with callback-based API. Promisesare provided for `request` with official `request-promise` package:

```
const request = require('request-promise');

function getEvents(sportId, federationId, date, locale)
{
    const options = {
        url: `http://myapi.com/sporting-event/sport/${sportId}/date-from/${date}`,
       headers: {
         'accept': 'application/json',
         'dateTo': date,
         'federationIds': federationId,
         'X-Application-ID': 'sportytrader',
         'Accept-Language': locale,
     };

     return request(options);
};

const getCachedEvents = memoize(
  getEvents,
  (...args) => JSON.stringify(args)
);

...

getCachedEvents(sportId, federationId, date, locale))
.then(body => res.send(body)
.catch(next);
```

Notice that due to how `JSON.stringify` works, this may affect how requests are cached, e.g. `undefined` and `null` arguments are not distinguished.

Comment: but that way can i check if one of my object has changed ?

Comment: so i guess after i call getCachedEvents inside my route but i have this error Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: It's not related to suggested solution. Regarding the error, I guess it means what it says, you likely did `res.send` somewhere else. Regarding unhandled rejection, it's handled in the code I provided. Do you have `catch` in your code? It should be there as a rule of thumb.